# when to prefer pessimistic model of transaction isolation over optimistic one?

Tags: sql-server, database, database-design, transactions, locking

Do I understand correctly that table/row lock hints are being used for pessimistic transaction (TX) isolation models of concurrency **ONLY**?
In other words, when can table/row lock hints be used during engagement of optimistic TX isolation provided by SQL Server (2005 and higher)?

When one would need pessimistic TX isolation levels/hints in SQL Server2005+ if the later provides built-in optimistic (aka snapshot aka versioning) concurrency isolation?
I did read that pessimistic options are legacy and are not needed anymore, though I am in doubt.

Also, having optimistic (aka snapshot aka versioning) TX isolation levels  built-in SQL Server2005+, 
when one would need to manually code for optimistic concurrency  features?

The last question is inspired by having read:

- ["Optimistic Concurrency in SQL Server" (September 28, 2007)](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2007/09/28/optimistic-concurrency-in-sql-server/)

describing custom coding to provide versioning in SQL Server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Optimistic concurrency requires more resources and is more expensive when the conflict occurs.

Two sessions can read and modify the values and the conflict only occurs when they try to apply their changes simultaneously. This means that in case of the concurrent update both values should be stored somewhere (which of course requires resources).

Also, when a conflict occurs, usually the whole transaction should be rolled back or the cursor refetched, which is expensive too.

Pessimistic concurrency model uses locking, thus downgrading concurrency but improving performance.

In case of two concurrent tasks, it may be cheaper for the second task to wait for a lock to release than spending `CPU` time and disk `I/O` on two simultaneous works and then yet more on rolling back the less fortunate work and redoing it.

Say, you have a query like this:

```
UPDATE  mytable
SET     myvalue = very_complex_function(@range)
WHERE   rangeid = @range
```

, with `very_complex_function` reading some data from `mytable` itself. In other words, this query transforms a subset of `mytable` sharing the value of `range`.

Now, when two functions work on the same range, there may be two scenarios:

1. Pessimistic: the first query locks, the second query waits for it. The first query completes in `10` seconds, the second one does too. Total: `20` seconds.
2. Optimistic: both queries work independently (on the same input). This shares `CPU` time between them plus some overhead on switching. They should keep their intermediate data somewhere, so the data is stored twice (which implies twice `I/O` or memory). Let's say both complete almost at the same time, in `15`seconds.

   But when it's time to commit the work, the second query will conflict and will have to rollback its changes (say, it takes the same `15` seconds). Then it needs to reread the data again and do the work again, with the new set of data (`10` seconds).

   As a result, *both* queries complete later than with a pessimistic locking: `15` and `40` seconds vs. `10` and `20`.

> When one would need pessimistic TX isolation levels/hints in SQL Server2005+ if the later provides built-in optimistic (aka snapshot aka versioning) concurrency isolation?

Optimistic isolation levels are, well, optimistic. You should not use them when you **expect** high contention on your data.

BTW, optimistic isolation (for the read queries) was available in `SQL Server 2000` too.

Comment: Great answer.  Just to put times on (2) for comparison, using your figures for (1) as indicative: both xacts take 20 secs; the first completes; the second is rolled back, another 20 secs; it retries and completes, another 20 secs. Total for second xact 60 secs.

Comment: can you further explain what did you mean under "optimistic isolation (for the read queries) was available in SQL Server 2000 too"?

Comment: @Quassnoi: I like your answer, but in the very common case where you *don't* have high write contention, optimistic locking typically performs better than pessimistic locking. Any chance you could mention that?

Comment: @antinome: what exactly do you mean by "performs better"?

Comment: @Quassnoi: I mean, with optimistic locking, no actual lock is ever acquired. While no conflicts are occurring (hopefully most of the time), there is essentially no performance penalty compared to not locking at all. Whereas, doesn't pessimistic locking incur some penalty for acquiring locks even when there is no conflict?

Comment: @antinome: something which tells "this record is affected" is acquired. If it's a lock, it prevents another transaction from reading (or making changes). If it's just a marker, it makes another transaction roll back on conflict. But the thing itself is still there.

Answer (score 2):

I have a detailed answer here: [Developing Modifications that Survive Concurrency](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/developing-modifications-that-survive-concurrency/)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bit confusion over terminology here.

The technique of optimistic locking/optimistic concurrency/... is a *programming* technique used to avoid the following scenario :

- start transaction
- read data, setting a "read" lock on it to prevent any deletes/modifications to our data
- display data on user's screen
- await user input, lock remains active
- keep awaiting user input, lock still preventing any writes/modifications
- user input never comes (for whatever reason)
- transaction times out (and this is usually not very rapidly, as the user must be given reasonable time to enter his input).

Optimistic locking replaces this with the following:

- start transaction READ
- read data, setting a "read" lock on it to prevent any deletes/modifications to our data
- end transaction READ, releasing the read lock just set
- display data on user's screen
- await user input, but data can be modified/deleted meanwhile by other transactions
- user input arrives
- start transaction WRITE
- verify that the data has remained unaltered, raising an exception if it has
- apply user updates
- end transaction WRITE

So the single "user transaction" to go fetch some data, and change and update them, consists of two distinct "database transactions".  What is usually called "isolation levels" applies to those database transactions.  The "optimistic locking" that you refer to applies to the "user transaction".

The matter is further complicated in that, broadly speaking, two completely distinct strategies are possible for the "isolating the database transactions part" :

- MVCC
- 2-phase locking

I think the "snapshot versioning isolation level" means that the MVCC technique (well, one of its various possible variations) is being used for the database transaction.  The other commonly known isolation levels apply more to transaction isolation using 2PL as the serialization(/isolation) technique.  (And mixing them up can get messy ...)

Comment: -1 Commendable attempt at clearing up a confused subject, but I disagree with the terms you are using (they are standard terms which have standard meaning, not what you have described).  The result is, while there might be less confusion re MS usage of terms, there is more confusion about the generic issues and standard terms.

Comment: @PerformanceDBA, thanks. I wanted to save a few minutes on concrete specific doubts and ended up spending hours to revise my knowledge of  basic terms definitions I knew for years. Unfortunately, your comments did not appear in my notifications (upon pressing envelope button). Now, I am in doubt should I add my own questions (and answers) to favorites in order to be notified on comments to replies to my own questions?

Comment: @vgv8: 1-The standards terms existed before MS bubbled up from Hell.  2-MS misused and abused to terms, & created their own terms that referenced std terms, fraudulently implying that they provided the function of the std terms; the usual dishonest marketing spin. 3-Now MS have (a) done it again with MVCC/2Pl and (b) invented terms based on their previous misleading terms, which are now *two* levels removed from the std terms, with no relation to the std function.  Eg. there is nothing whatsoever "optimistic" about MVCC, or "pessimistic" about 2PL; in fact, it is the opposite.  Will post.